# print all product combination of array

Tags: algorithm, combinations

An array of integer `a[] = {3, 5, 7}`// array elements are unique 
print all product combination:

`input :` 3, 5, 7 
`output:` 3, 5, 7, 15, 21, 35, 105

Recently I have been asked this question in interview. I Couldn't think of approach.  please suggest the approach/code.

Comment: Was there any requirement to check for duplicates in results?  Like 2, 3, 6, 7 would have duplicates since 2*3*7 = 6*7

Comment: In general you have 2^n products here (each element can be present or not), but checking for duplicates is another thing

Comment: @TimothyHa In general it have 2^n - 1 because it is like selecting a sub set from a set, and we cant have 0 element subset so it is 2^n - 1 products. (but as you say there still maybe some duplicate , ... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple recursive function:

```
def all_products(S,A,base=1):
    """Add all products of base times elements from the array A to set S"""
    S.add(base)
    if A:
        all_products(S,A[1:],base)
        all_products(S,A[1:],base*A[0])

S=set()
all_products(S, [3, 5, 7])
print sorted(S)
```

This approach also includes the result (1) of multiplying none of the elements together.

Comment: I like the way S.add takes care of uniqueness of a product.  Nice thing for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here is java code for creating the Set that you wanted :

```
import java.util.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
        Set<Integer> ints = new HashSet<Integer>();

        ints.add(3);
        ints.add(5);
        ints.add(7);

        ints = mainClass.recursiveSetCreator(ints);

        printOutput(ints);
    }

    private static void printOutput(Set<Integer> ints) {
        List list = new ArrayList(ints);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public Set<Integer> recursiveSetCreator(Set<Integer> recInput) {
        if (recInput.size() == 1) {
            return recInput;
        }
        List integerList = new ArrayList(recInput);
        Integer lastItem = (Integer) integerList.remove(integerList.size() - 1);
        recInput.remove(lastItem);
        recInput = recursiveSetCreator(recInput);
        int size = recInput.size();
        integerList = new ArrayList(recInput);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Integer item = (Integer) integerList.get(i);
            recInput.add(item * lastItem);
        }
        recInput.add(lastItem);
        return recInput;
    }
}
```

You can see the running version on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/h7Lk1l)